# How to get number of pageviews for each page in website

Tags: asp.net, google-api

I am tracking my website using google analytics code. I want to display number of pageviews of each page where user visiting pages of my website. Does google api provides any code to display number of pageviews of each page in website? Can any one please help me in this?

I used following code

```
        DataQuery dataQuery = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);
        dataQuery.Ids = profileId;
        dataQuery.Metrics = "ga:pageviews";
        dataQuery.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
        dataQuery.Sort = "ga:browser,ga:pageviews";
        dataQuery.GAStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dataQuery.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

but it throws exception as follows
           Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?          dimensions=ga:pagePath&end-date=2012-07-27&ids=ga:46119231&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=ga:browser,ga:pageviews&start-date=2012-06-27

can u please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/119/Displaying-Google-Analytics-Data-in-ASP.NET) for retrieving data in Asp.net 
and for php you can have [this](http://davidwalsh.name/php-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google analytics core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to do this.

According to the documentation on the page

> Querying for Dimensions and Metrics
>
> You query the API for Google Analytics report data, which consists of
>   dimensions and metrics. Metrics are the individual measurements of
>   visitor activity on your site, **such as visits and pageviews**.
>   Dimensions break down metrics across some common criteria, such as
>   country or browser. When you build a query, you specify which
>   dimensions and metrics you want in your report data.

So i guess you should be able to do it

Comment: hi i edited my question again, can you please review my above question and response for that?

Comment: can you please help me how to querying for dimensions and metrics since am not aware of this?

Comment: i tried dataQuery.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath" as you suggested in my code. but it throws exception

Comment: what exception are you getting ?, If it is an 401 Authorization required exception, then you need to authorize your app for more check [Core reporting Api - Authorization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization)

Comment: exception am getting is: Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data? dimensions=ga:pagePath&end-date=2012-07-27&ids=ga:46119231&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=ga:browser,ga:pageviews&start-date=2012-06-27

Comment: Have yu tried this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/a/11706749/507184 by vinoaj

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `ga:browser` in your list of fetched dimensions, and you're trying to sort by that field. Adding it to your dimensions, or removing it from your sort criteria, should fix the problem.